# Invoke Keycloak Challenge on User Action

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

I have set up keycloak as Authentication provider and I can login to my application using the code flow etc.

Now I have a requirement to add additional authentication challenges when a user tries to do a specific action - let's say transfer money over a given sum.

My current line of thought is to have one initial *accessToken* that has a restricted scope and when the user tries to do the money transfer - initiate another login process that follows some custom flow.

What is the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

That is an interesting flow, one which I would also like to know what would be the best way to implement according to the best security patterns.

> Now I have a requirement to add additional authentication challenges
> when a user tries to do a specific action - let's say transfer money
> over a given sum.

My current design proposal would be for the *second authentication phase*  to use a typical method for 2FA. That could be for example [OTP](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#proc_creating-otp_server_administration_guide) (One-time password), which comes with its own [set of advantages and disadvantages](https://www.tools4ever.com/glossary/what-is-otp/). Bear in mind that you can overcome some of those disadvantages by configuring `WebAuthn` in Keycloak.

So a hard draft would be to have a pop window where the user would insert the OTP code, and in the background, you could have a custom version of the direct grand flow where you remove the need for the password and only require the OTP code. Additional information like the username could be obtained from the original access token that you get after the user is successfully authenticated. The benefit of this approach is that it would work with users coming from external IdPs, and you do not need to redirect the user again to the Keycloak login page. Since I am not a security expert I cannot tell from the top of my head what are the security problems with this approach.

Comment: Would it possible to secure the second login and tell it that it is only available for users who passed the first login ?

Comment: Yes, when your application makes the direct grand rest call, the application can send the username is on the access token from the first login